# vspace after maketitle doesn't work

Tags: longtable, titles

I'm trying to make a title page with a background and a changelog (subsection with longtable) *(company policy)

The changelog should start in the title page, and extend to the next page if necessary.

I renewed the `\maketitle` command to make easier later on for the design team (guy) to make a title page accordingly.

But I'm having a problem with the `\vfill`.

If I have the title with the wallpaper, all good, but if I uncomment the changelog part, all `\vfill` stop working.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

% Column type so changelog can strech the whole page
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\textbf{System}}\par
        {\LARGE\textbf{Sub-title}}\par
        \vspace*{\fill}
        {\Large author}\par
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
}

%-------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{0.5}{cover_placeholder.png}
    \maketitle
    %-------------------------------------------------
    %   CHANGELOG
    %-------------------------------------------------
    % \vspace*{\fill}
    % \subsubsection*{Changelog}
    % \begin{longtable}{@{} L{0.05\textwidth} L{0.15\textwidth} L{0.7\textwidth} @{}}
    %     \toprule
    %     v0.1 & 2022-10-02 & First Draft \\
    %     v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    %     \bottomrule
    % \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I'm using pdflatex to compile

P.S.: All the preamble is in a different file, but the changelog would be placed in the document (because I even tried placing the table inside the `\maketitle`)

Comment: Is the problem with the title page containing Changelog, which is supposed to be on the next page? Does it work If you add `\clearpage` after `\vspace*{\fill}`, inside the `\maketitle`?

Comment: using ```\clearpage``` solve the```\vfill``` part, as well as a ```\newpage``` after the ```\maketitle``` would, but the changelog should start in the title page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is to use `tikz` because you can put different nodes on top of each other, which can contain text or images. Additionally, `tikz` offer to set an opacity of its nodes.

If you put `tikzpicture` inside `minipage` of fixed height and the middle alignment `[c]`, you will have the same effect of uniform spacing before and after an image because. Even if I am not exactly to the point, I believe this approach will give you more flexibility, anyway.

Note, I have used `\vspace{\stretch{n}}` between elements of the title (inside the second node and parbox). This adds variate stretching instead of uniformed `\fill`; in fact, the latter is equivalent of using `\stretch{1}` everywhere. It requires either `minipage` or `\parbox` with the third option `inner-pos` set to `[s]`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Column type so changelog can strech the whole page
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\textheight-4cm]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (I) [opacity=0.3] {\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=11cm]{example-image-duck}};
            \node (T) {\parbox[c][9cm][s]{11cm}{\mytitle}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}}

\newcommand\mytitle{%    
    \centering
    {\Huge\textbf{System}}\par
    \vspace{\stretch{1}}   % use \fill for uniform spacing
    {\LARGE\textbf{Sub-title}}\par
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
    {\Large author}}
    

%-------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%-------------------------------------------------
%   CHANGELOG
%-------------------------------------------------
\subsubsection*{Changelog}
\begin{longtable}{@{} L{0.05\textwidth} L{0.15\textwidth} L{0.7\textwidth} @{}}
    \toprule
    v0.1 & 2022-10-02 & First Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    v0.2 & 2022-11-20 & Last Draft \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, can I ask why my approach didn't work though?

Comment: I'll try. You mixed a fixed picture at the centre with a flexible title arrangement (`\vspace{\fill}`). There, `longtable` grows upward first consuming all infinite glue (`\fill`) before it starts the next page. A fixed spacing like `\vspace{3cm}` would work but only if used before and after a box with the title. It would still need some tuning by try and error and the title itself would still need to be in a `minipage` with stretchable space and `[s]` option.

Comment: ... The exact same effect was accomplished by placing a tall `minipage` with the middle alignment by default, which is simply an equivalent of adding `\vspace{\fill}` by hand. A fixed height needs to be set. Otherwise, `minipage` would take the height of the `tikzpicture`. As a side note, `tikz` is very helpful in many ways.

Comment: So, by adding a ```longtable``` all the glue is squished together. I would need to first need to create a fixed box (unsquishable) so that ```longtable``` couldn't take the space?

Comment: Yes and no! Yes, that's what `\fill` does: adds spacing between 0 and maximum. If you wanted to keep everything in one page with the `longtable`, your example would almost be correct. You would just need to get rid of `wallpaper` and substitute it with `tikzpicture` with an image and text in one element.

Comment: ... No because "unshakeable" box itself would not  help. Glues and stretchable spacing are responsible for moving things around. You would have to fix them.